# .sh script will not let me loop through files

Tags: bash, ssh, debian

I am trying to print out my files on /var/www/ but for some reason I get this error: 
"temp.sh: line 3: FILES: command not found"

Code:

`#loop through files
FILES = /var/www/*
for f in $FILES
do
    echo "processing $f"
done`

I am running this from the home directory by command line like this sh script.sh (if that matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a variable in sh, there cannot be any spaces before or after the `=` character.  Change your code to

```
FILES=/var/www/*
```

However, this will have problems if any of the files in `/var/www` have spaces in their names, as they'll be split after variable substitution in your `for` line.  So if there's a file like `name with space`, you'll get

```
processing /var/www/name
processing with
processing space
```

You can avoid that by putting the pattern *directly* in the `for` command, as pathname expansion occurs *after* word splitting:

```
for f in /var/www/*; do
    echo "processing $f"
done
```

and you'll get `processing /var/www/name with space`

Alternately, you can use a variable for the directory -- you just need to insure that the wildcards are in the `for` line to get the expansion/splitting in the correct order:

```
FILE_DIR=/var/www
for f in $FILE_DIR/*; do
```

Comment: Bingo Bango! That Solved it.

Comment: +1: Or, alternatively again, `FILES=(/var/www/*); for file in "${FILES[@]}"; do …whatever…; done`, using an array to store the names.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That works, but only with bash -- other sh implementations don't support arrays.

Comment: Well, some other shells support arrays...but not all.  Korn shell does, for one.  The question is tagged `bash`, so using a `bash` feature is not unreasonable.